# UITableViewCell height not changing with custom height

Tags: ios, css, uitableview

when I run my program, the table cell is at the default 44, even though I have it set to 68 in my program. I'm using the same TableViewCell for two different TableViewControllers. At run time, one of them is showing up with the custom height of 68, but the other changes to the default 44.

[image]

[image]

I've included images of what happens to each table at run time. I am also getting the following error:

```html
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fixes it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000096ad0 UIButton:0x7f7fead24c10.width == 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000094be0 'UISV-canvas-connection' FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x7f7fead25800.leading == UIButton:0x7f7fead24c10.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008b130 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[UIButton:0x7f7fead24c10]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x7f7fead25800 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008c120 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x7f7fead25800.width == 56   (active)>"
)


class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    var meals = [Meal]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
        
        loadSampleMeals()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return meals.count
    }
    

    
   


    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MealTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")
        }
        
        // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
        let meal = meals[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name
        cell.priceLabel.text = meal.price
        cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo
        cell.ratingControl.rating = meal.rating
        
        return cell
    }
    

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    
    //MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        
        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
            case "ShowDetail":
            guard let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MealViewController else {
                    fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
            }
            
            guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender)")
            }
            
            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
            }
            
            let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
            mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal
            
        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier)")
        }
    }
    
    
    //MARK: Private Methods
    
    /*
     // Follow this format
     guard let meal1 = Meal(name: "", price: "$", photo: , rating: , calories: "Calories: ", description: "Description:  ") else {
     fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal1")
     }
     */
    
    private func loadSampleMeals() {
        
        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "Sprite")
        let photo2 = UIImage(named: "HotCheetos")
        let photo3 = UIImage(named: "Nachos")

        guard let meal1 = Meal(name: "Sprite", price: "$1.50", photo: photo1, rating: 0, calories: "Calories: 129", description: "Description: A refreshing lemon-lime soda") else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal1")
        }

        guard let meal2 = Meal(name: "Hot Cheetos", price: "$1.50", photo: photo2, rating: 0, calories: "Calories: 160", description: "Description: A spicy version of original cheetos") else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
        }

        guard let meal3 = Meal(name: "Nachos", price: "$1.50", photo: photo3, rating: 0, calories: "Calories: 436", description: "Description: Tortilla chips with a side of smooth nacho cheese") else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
        }

        meals += [meal1, meal2, meal3]
    }

}


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000096ad0 UIButton:0x7f7fead24c10.width == 44   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I am using auto layout and have put no constraints on. I am very confused why one table resets to default sizing even though they are the same class

I have added the code for the TableViewController below the error message

Comment: Jaros can you show some code.?

Comment: Jaros where have you used heightforrow method?

Answer (score 1):

Click on your UITableViewCell, open the right pane, and in the Size Inspector make sure the Custom checkbox is **checked** next to Row Height. The value you specify here is a default cell height, but will only be overridden if the Custom box is checked and you have defined heightForRowAt indexPath.

If you're still getting the same error, there must be something else completely unrelated that is breaking.

Comment: The custom box is checked. I don't think I have defined heightForRowAt indexPath though?

Comment: That's your problem exactly, IF you're trying to achieve dynamic cell height for the same cell.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
  var defaultHeight = CGFloat(68.0)
  
  if someValueIsTrue
  {
   defaultHeight -= CGFloat(14.0)
  }
  
  return defaultHeight
 }